# Review queues can be accessed after reached 500 reputation, but the review queue page says differently

Tags: support, bug, review, help-center

As per the [Review Queues introduction page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro), "First Posts" and "Late Answers" can be earned at 2,000 reputation.
But I can access those review queues, after reached 500 reputation in all the Stack Exchange sites.

Also in the same page, I see the following information:

> Once you have achieved 2,000 reputation, you have access to the first set of Review queues ...

That is not correct, after reached 500 reputation we can access the review queues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange doesn't have First Posts and Late Answers review queues, and hence the [first paragraph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro) is correct:

> Once you have achieved 2,000 reputation, you have access to the first set of Review queues

The *real* problem is that the same help page is used network-wide; the privilege levels are inserted on-the-fly. So it looks correct on e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro):

[image]

[Here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro) you see one for a beta site with yet another set of reputation amounts.

It would be better if references to missing queues are removed altogether, but I suspect that is rather difficult. Perhaps a footnote like the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) would work?

> Note: The First posts and Late answers queues do not exist on [Meta sites](/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 3):

I think that is mentioned **only for Meta SE** (2k limit). For example I have less than 2k rep in Meta SE and I can't have reviews.

[image]

But in Workplace I have > 500 rep but < 2k rep, and I can review there and it's also mentioned in their [help page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro).

[image]

In every other SE site and also in Stack Overflow the minimum rep to do certain reviews is 500.

Edit: After noticing [@Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)'s post, I came to know that the **minimum rep in certain sites are even less than 500 rep.**

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots